# I am getting this error on selenium 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'options'

Tags: python-3.x, selenium

```
select = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//select[@id="select_noti_segments_in"]').click()
for index in range(len(select.options)):
        select = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//select[@id="select_noti_segments_in"]')
        select.select_by_index(1)
        time.sleep(5)
```

**for index in range(len(select.options)):
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'options'**
**I am getting this error when i run the python script may i know why i am getting this and how can i resolve this**

Answer (score 1):

Simply remove call of `click` from `select` definition:

```
select = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//select[@id="select_noti_segments_in"]')
```

Also you need to import `Select` class and use it as below:

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select

select = Select(driver.find_element_by_id('select_noti_segments_in'))
select.select_by_index(1)
```

Comment: for index in range(len(select.option)):
AttributeError: 'WebElement' object has no attribute 'option'   then i am getting this error

Comment: @souravsharan , try second solution